# Operator Box Without Needing to Drag

Tags: bevel, operator

Is there a way to bring up the Operator Box without needing to start a Bevel with my mouse. I'm used to using 3DS MAX. I'm used to typing the bevel amount without needing to drag a piece first,

Answer (score 2):

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> right away, then tweak the parameters in the *Operator Box*.

Comment: It doesn't work with each other thing like extrude, etc. I want to be able to skip needing to drag before the Operator Box  shows up.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, t works with extrude as well @Joseph Ibinson